# rails simple form date input - separate integer inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, simple-form

I have a date column in my schema called `dob`.

I'm using a simple form to render the `dob`.
I want to format the input as 3 separate integer inputs.
The closest i have gotten is this code:
`<%= f.input :dob, order: [:day, :month, :year] %>`

However it produces this:

[image]

which is close. However i need the inputs to be integer inputs, and not dropdowns. Also i would like the month the be an integer as well.
If i use `as: :integer`, it just returns one single input.
Any ideas? The simple form documentation is not particularly helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you will need 3 integer inputs:

```rb
f.integer :day
f.integer :month
f.integer :year
```

This requires you to have day, month, and year attribute accessors on your model, and to assemble the date from the component integers, perhaps in the controller, e.g.

```rb
# users_controller.rb
def create
  params[:dob] = Date.new(params[:year], params[:month], params[:day])
  #... the rest of the method
end
```

in order to populate the integer fields for editing, you'll need methods on your model, e.g.

```rb
# in User.rb
def day
  dob.day
end
# ...etc
```

You will also need to check that the data that the user inputs is within range.
All this special handling is why this is not normally done.